# MATLAB: Merging two similar Text fields

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two arrays with similar text field, county and state. I need to merge these two arrays based on common county and state information. A simple example is shown here:

```
A = [Alabama    Chambers    36571
     Alabama    Cherokee    24006
     Alabama    Cherokee    24006
     Alabama    Jackson     53979
     Alabama    Jefferson   662033]

B = [2397530 -85.448 34.202 -86 35  Cherokee  Alabama
     2423130 -86.599 33.622 -86 33  Jefferson Alabama
     2423398 -86.576 33.524 -86 33  Jefferson Alabama
     2423496 -86.784 33.369 -86 33  Jefferson Alabama
     2455980 -86.696 33.711 -86 33  Jefferson Alabama
     2457595 -86.868 33.597 -86 33  Jefferson Alabama
     2458450 -86.879 33.518 -86 33  Jefferson Alabama];
```

Resulting third matrix:

```
C = [2397530 -85.448 34.202 -86 35  Cherokee Alabama  24006
     2423130 -86.599 33.622 -86 33  Jefferson Alabama 662033
     2423398 -86.576 33.524 -86 33  Jefferson Alabama 662033
     2423496 -86.784 33.369 -86 33  Jefferson Alabama 662033
     2455980 -86.696 33.711 -86 33  Jefferson Alabama 662033
     2457595 -86.868 33.597 -86 33  Jefferson Alabama 662033
     2458450 -86.879 33.518 -86 33  Jefferson Alabama 662033];
```

Comment: Hum? what happened there? can you explain the rules of the merging?

Comment: Just checking: are they really matrices or rather cell arrays?

Comment: Rule of merging is I am trying to merge data field of matrix A with corresponding text field in matrix B. Matrix B also has repeated county information, then it will take that information from matrix A. I think it's matching cell arrays not sure guys. Any help is appreciable!

Comment: But how'd you create all the numeric data in the last matrix? They seem to come out of nowhere

Comment: intersect or ismember should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this answer I assume that variable 'A' and 'B' are both cell arrays, and match those given in the initial question.

Supposing that you know the State/County information is always in the same column (1 & 2 for 'A', 7 & 6 for 'B'), you can use the following code to loop through 'A', compare with State/County information in 'B', and then append the relevant information onto 'B' (what appears to be desired is to append the 3rd column of 'A' onto the end of matching rows of 'B').

```
stateIdxA=1;
countyIdxA=2;
stateIdxB=7;
countyIdxB=6;
appendIdxA=size(A,2); %We want to append the last element from A
appendIdxB=size(B,2)+1; % We want to append it to the end of B
for m = 1:size(B,1)
    jointStateCountyB{m} = [B{m,stateIdxB},B{m,countyIdxB}];
end

C=B; %Setup third cell array C to append to

for n = 1:size(A,1)
    jointStateCountyA = [A{n,stateIdxA},A{n,countyIdxA}];
    isSame = strcmp(jointStateCountyA,jointStateCountyB);
    C(isSame,appendIdxB) = A(n,appendIdxA);
end
```

Comment: I am getting blank cells.

Comment: I tested this code using cell arrays of the example data given, the same as the arrays shown in the answer by sclarke81. It should work for cell arrays of any length. Can you put in your question or reply here with the type displayed by Matlab for your versions of 'A' and 'B'? The only reason I've been able to come up with why this method would not work is if the variables aren't actually cell arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a one-liner with tables.

I've assumed that your data is in cell arrays like so:

```
A = { 'Alabama', 'Chambers',  36571
      'Alabama', 'Cherokee',  24006
      'Alabama', 'Jackson',   53979
      'Alabama', 'Jefferson', 662033 };

B = { 2397530, -85.448, 34.202, -86, 35,  'Cherokee',  'Alabama'
      2423130, -86.599, 33.622, -86, 33,  'Jefferson', 'Alabama'
      2423398, -86.576, 33.524, -86, 33,  'Jefferson', 'Alabama'
      2423496, -86.784, 33.369, -86, 33,  'Jefferson', 'Alabama'
      2455980, -86.696, 33.711, -86, 33,  'Jefferson', 'Alabama'
      2457595, -86.868, 33.597, -86, 33,  'Jefferson', 'Alabama'
      2458450, -86.879, 33.518, -86, 33,  'Jefferson', 'Alabama' };
```

Then all you need to do is this:

```
C = table2cell(innerjoin(cell2table(A), cell2table(B), 'LeftKeys', [1, 2], 'RightKeys', [7, 6]));
```

Which produces this:

```
C = 

    'Alabama'    'Cherokee'     [ 24006]    [2397530]    [-85.4480]    [34.2020]    [-86]    [35]
    'Alabama'    'Jefferson'    [662033]    [2423130]    [-86.5990]    [33.6220]    [-86]    [33]
    'Alabama'    'Jefferson'    [662033]    [2423398]    [-86.5760]    [33.5240]    [-86]    [33]
    'Alabama'    'Jefferson'    [662033]    [2423496]    [-86.7840]    [33.3690]    [-86]    [33]
    'Alabama'    'Jefferson'    [662033]    [2455980]    [-86.6960]    [33.7110]    [-86]    [33]
    'Alabama'    'Jefferson'    [662033]    [2457595]    [-86.8680]    [33.5970]    [-86]    [33]
    'Alabama'    'Jefferson'    [662033]    [2458450]    [-86.8790]    [33.5180]    [-86]    [33]
```

Comment: both solutions are promising! Thanks :)

Comment: I checked with this. The problem I am encountering, the size of matrix A is 3114x3 and matrix B is 147x7. So, neither of these two are working. Any help?

Comment: What do you mean not working? Do you get any error messages? Can you confirm that your data is in cell arrays? Does the first bit of code I've posted accurately produce the same data type/structure that you have? The more information you provide the more likely we will be able to help.